# Speed up loading page by disabling event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a too big page ~2.5MB compressed size, and it's loading about ~1min. 
This is too long and I finding ways to speed up it. I have following stack trace of event that occurs regulary in 100Kb content loaded. I suspect this is the reason why page is loading slowly. Any thoughts how it can be disabled?

> GC Event - Details Duration   1.000ms (at 9.61s) Collected    643.82KB Used
>   Heap Size 51.28MB of 64.93MB Call Stack    jQuery.ajaxTransport.send
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.js:8102 jQuery.extend.ajax  @  jquery-1.7.1.js:7580
>   evalScript     @  jquery-1.7.1.js:6427 jQuery.extend.each 
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.js:658 jQuery.fn.extend.domManip
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.js:5984 jQuery.fn.extend.append     @  jquery-1.7.1.js:5761
>   jQuery.fn.extend.wrapAll   @  jquery-1.7.1.js:5718
>   jQuery.fn.extend.wrapInner     @  jquery-1.7.1.js:5736 jQuery.extend.each 
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.js:658 jQuery.fn.jQuery.each    @  jquery-1.7.1.js:271
>   jQuery.fn.extend.wrapInner     @  jquery-1.7.1.js:5731
>   $.extend.initializePage    @  jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:7503 (anonymous
>   function)  @  jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:7570 jQuery.Callbacks.fire
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.js:1046 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith 
>   @ jquery-1.7.1.js:1164 jQuery.extend.ready     @  jquery-1.7.1.js:435
>   DOMContentLoaded   @  jquery-1.7.1.js:923

Comment: What about image compression?

Comment: There is no images. And page is compress already.

Comment: Could you show your biggest files?

Comment: what are you sending? I would look into dynamic pages: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html send JSON and let jQM build the html

Comment: I send already generated html markup. The count of items is too big and it better to render it on the server rather than client. I don't know why jQM fires such event.

Comment: Does the page contain a Long list?

Comment: No, if you mean <li>,<ul> tags.